# JQGrid Display group field data in one page if pagination is applied

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

In JQGrid I want to show group data on one page. That is, if containing all of the items in an order would exceed the list limit, then no items from that order are contained and the list is simply slightly shorter than the limit and shows data to previous order. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that this should be done at server and not at client grid. If I understand right , suppose you have 10 items limit per page and the response contain 8 from one group and 2 from the other -  if the second group contain really 2 items, which will be deleted,  this will be not correct.
In case there are more records from previous page - the previous deleted 2 records should be included into the next page, but according to your server response they will be missed.

Comment: Yes, If page limit is 10, Records contains two groups first group has 8 records and and second has 4 records in that case page should show 8 records of first group. I tried doing it from server side it was working fine but I when i select 20 records from pagination dropdown it doesn't work correctly. I can't handle it from server side

Comment: This is not a trivial task as seen at first look. As I say, doing this client side in all cases there will be a problems with displaying records and making sums if any.